# uploaded file via filezilla to proftp server(on ubuntu 14.04 lts) but reported 550 error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

uploaded file via filezilla to proftp server(on ubuntu 14.04 lts) but reported 550 error

```
550 download.html: Permission denied
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

I try to set the directory to chmod 777

but error is same

ftp for download is OK

your comment welcome

Comment: What are you trying to do? 550 is http and not FTP...
Did you upload a file via FTP that you can't download using HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same thing happened to me after upgrading from Precise Pangolin to Trusty Tahr. I investigated and it looks like `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, the FTP configuration file, was one of the configuration files amended during the upgrade. Specifically, this line:

```
write_enable=YES
```

which I had previously uncommented was now commented again. I uncommented it, restarted the FTP server (sudo restart vsftpd) and suddenly I could upload and amend file permissions again.